# multinomial logit

Tags: r, statistics, economics, mlogit

I'm stuck with running a multinomial logit regression in R. The data preview is attached for the reference. How should I run it? I'm new to R, and need to do this for applied econometrics using R. Can you help me with reshaping data and running multinomial regression?

```
> head(data)
  marketindex x1_prod1 x2_prod1 x3_prod1 x1_prod2 x2_prod2 x3_prod2 x1_prod3 x2_prod3 x3_prod3 x1_prod0 x2_prod0 x3_prod0 choice
1           1 7.459917        1 7.267866  6.67054        1 7.633743 8.444682        0 11.30016        0        0        0      3
2           1 7.459917        1 7.267866  6.67054        1 7.633743 8.444682        0 11.30016        0        0        0      2
3           1 7.459917        1 7.267866  6.67054        1 7.633743 8.444682        0 11.30016        0        0        0      3
4           1 7.459917        1 7.267866  6.67054        1 7.633743 8.444682        0 11.30016        0        0        0      2
5           1 7.459917        1 7.267866  6.67054        1 7.633743 8.444682        0 11.30016        0        0        0      2
6           1 7.459917        1 7.267866  6.67054        1 7.633743 8.444682        0 11.30016        0        0        0      2
```

Comment: Could you copy-paste some parts of the data as text using `dput(yourdata)`? I am using an internet provider that blocks the site that stores your image so I can't see it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running multinomial logit model in R can be done in several packages, including `multinom` package and `mlogit` package. The tutorial at UCLA website recommended by mhmtsrmn prefers `multinom` to `mlogit`

> because it does not require the data to be reshaped (as the mlogit
> package does)

However, the data you provided have been in a shape compatible with the format required by `mlogit` package, so in case you want to use `mlogit`, you don't need reshaping anymore. Nevertheless, you do need to change the coding in the `choice` column as follows:

- Choice `2` must be changed to `prod2`
- Choice `3` must be changed to `prod3`, and so on.

This is necessary because in the other columns you use `prod2`, `prod3`, etc.

I tried to run `mlogit` function to your data sample, but it failed, most probably because this sample doesn't have enough variation in its values. So I change the values to random values and assigned the data frame to `choice_dat` name, like this:

```
choice_dat
 marketindex x1_prod1 x2_prod1 x3_prod1 x1_prod2 x2_prod2 x3_prod2 x1_prod3
1           1        5        7        6        5        2        8        7
2           1        8        3        5        6        3        9        8
3           1        7       10        3        7        6        9        9
4           1        8        8        2        5        8        9        7
5           1        9        9       10        8        4        6        8
6           1        7        4        8        7       10       10        8
  x2_prod3 x3_prod3 x1_prod0 x2_prod0 x3_prod0 choice1
1       10       13        0        0        0   prod3
2        3       10        0        0        0   prod2
3        4       10        0        0        0   prod3
4        1       11        0        0        0   prod2
5        8       10        0        0        0   prod2
6        5       12        0        0        0   prod2
```

Then, I run `mlogit` to the data:

```
prod_dat <- dfidx(choice_dat, choice = "choice1", varying = c(2:13), sep = "_")
mod1<- mlogit(choice1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3|0, data = prod_dat)
summary(mod1)

Call:
mlogit(formula = choice1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | 0, data = prod_dat, 
    method = "nr")

Frequencies of alternatives:choice
  prod0   prod1   prod2   prod3 
0.00000 0.00000 0.66667 0.33333 

nr method
5 iterations, 0h:0m:0s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 9.53E-08 
gradient close to zero 

Coefficients :
   Estimate Std. Error z-value Pr(>|z|)
x1 -0.11412    0.38947 -0.2930   0.7695
x2  0.16461    0.17790  0.9253   0.3548
x3  0.26768    0.22651  1.1818   0.2373

Log-Likelihood: -5.8257
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How could I write a multinomial logit score function manually to compute these without package?

Comment: Specifically the question is about coding a function of β that returns the score vector of the observed data..

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by 'the score vector of the observed data'. But please take a look at Kenneth Train's excellent book https://eml.berkeley.edu/books/choice2.html. Maybe you can find the answer in Chapter 6 or 8

Comment: It is basically computing all these coefficients by writing out the maximum likelihood function for multinomial logit

Comment: Please see Ch.8 page 185

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/) to multinomial logistics regression example in R using `multinom` from `nnet` package by UCLA. The formula format looks like the same as base R's `lm` function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `multinom(...)` example, using your data.

```
library(data.table)
library(nnet)
setDT(data)
##
#   first method
#
data[
  , c('x1', 'x2', 'x3'):=mget(sapply(1:3, function(x) sprintf('x%d_prod%d', x, choice)))
  , by=.(1:nrow(data))]
fit.1 <- multinom(choice ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data)
fit.1
## Call:
## multinom(formula = choice ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = data)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)          x1          x2          x3 
##   -3.420470   -6.949344  -12.363971    6.679612 
##
## Residual Deviance: 0.0001212278 
## AIC: 4.000121 
##
#   alternate method
#
data.melt <- melt(data, measure.vars = patterns('_prod'))
data.melt[, prod.id:=gsub('^.+_prod(\\d+)$', '\\1',variable)]
data.melt[, variable:=gsub('^(.+)_.+$', '\\1', variable)]
data.melt <- data.melt[choice==prod.id]
data.melt[, id:=seq(.N), by=.(variable, choice)]
mf <- dcast(data.melt, marketindex+choice+id~variable, value.var = 'value')
fit.2 <- multinom(choice ~ x1+x2+x3, mf)
fit.2
## Call:
## multinom(formula = choice ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = mf)
##
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)          x1          x2          x3 
##   -3.420470   -6.949344  -12.363971    6.679612 
##
## Residual Deviance: 0.0001212278 
## AIC: 4.000121
```